# helm upgrade fail with error: UPGRADE FAILED: "chart-repository" has no deployed releases

Tags: kubernetes, helm

I am trying to upgrade a chart but when I run upgrade command, upgrade fails with the following error.

```
nit:~/copy> helm upgrade chart-repository chart-repository/
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: "chart-repository" has no deployed releases
```

but when I do `helm list -A` , it looks to me it is deployed.

```
nit:~/copy> helm ls -A
NAME                NAMESPACE   REVISION    UPDATED                                 STATUS      CHART                   APP VERSION
chart-repository    charts      1           2021-06-08 14:43:05.186875759 +0000 UTC deployed    chart-repository-0.0.16 0.0.14
```

So, why is the upgrade failing?
i am using helm 3.6.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing namespace in the upgrade command. Following should work:

```
helm upgrade chart-repository chart-repository/ -n charts
```

Comment: hi, thanks. that worked but i am getting this error. any idea why i might be guessing this `error: UPGRADE FAILED: cannot patch "chart-repository-chartmuseum" with kind Deployment: Deployment.apps "chart-repository-chartmuseum" is invalid: spec.selector: Invalid value: v1.LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{"app.kubernetes.io/instance":"chart-repository", "app.kubernetes.io/name":"chartmuseum"}, MatchExpressions:[]v1.LabelSelectorRequirement(nil)}: field is immutable`

Comment: So selector changed and it does not support this kind of upgrade. What you can do - delete this deployment via kubectl (kubectl delete deployment chart-repository-chartmuseum) - and then re-do the helm upgrade command. Note that this would cause some downtime.

Comment: + Feel free to join my Discord for quick questions - https://discord.gg/UTxjBf9juQ - I curate that and here I can miss something